# Get all the images within a class call post with jquery

Tags: jquery, title

Hi I just discovered jquery, but can't figure out how i can get all the imgs within a class
and add a rel tag and set its title.

I understood that class can be added like this:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.entry-content img').addClass('myClass yourClass');
    });
    </script>
```

But is there something to set title and rel? like

```
$('.entry-content img').addrel('myClass yourClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.entry-content img').addClass('myClass yourClass')
                         .attr({ title: "some Title", rel: "some Rel" });
});
```